# How to make navbar with responsive images/icons in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to resize an action toolbar with images/icons. I have already implemented it using Bootstrap 3 navbar and everything seems to be working nicely.

However an action bar is a bit too big, and so I need to resize it down. The problem is that the images/icons inside the navbar do not scale down if I try to decrease navbar height and I couldnt figure out a way to make them responsive to the navbar container.

Does anyone know how to implement an action toolbar with images that would be truly responsive? (images scale up or down depending on the action toolbar height/size?)

Here is an example HTML of a toolbar in question (with a few example images):

**HTML:**

```
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse action-bar-policies">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          Action
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/facebook-icon.png" alt="Contact customer"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/twitter-icon.png" alt="Create task"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/google-plus-icon.png" alt="Accounting"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://static.iconarchive.com/static/images/social/blogger-icon.png" alt="Create quote"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/modify_policy.png" alt="Modify policy"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/suspend_policy.png" alt="Suspend policy"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/reinstate_policy.png" alt="Reinstate policy"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/cancel_policy.png" alt="Cancel policy"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/validate_policy.png" alt="Validate policy"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/move_policy.png" alt="Move policy to another account"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="icons/refresh.png" alt="Refresh content"></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.action-bar-policies.navbar {
  min-height:20px;
}

.action-bar-policies > .navbar-nav  > li > a {
  padding-top:3px;
  padding-bottom:3px;
}

.action-bar-policies .navbar-brand {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use javascript to determine the width and the height of the navbar and set the width and height of the images automatically according to that. If not, use media queries to change the image sizes according to browser size (which will be the main reason that your navbars size changes)

Comment: Thank you, changing image size directly seems like a very good workaround and I am going to use that if no better solution is found. I would still like to know however if it is possible to style all images through the navbar size somehow. Preferably without using any jQuery as my presentation layer needs to be done with Angular

Comment: I havent done many work with Angular unfortunately :/ but I would day it is possible with Angular but I dont know how , sorry ...